# Regex in TCL: Only allow numbers 0-9 and one special word

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to check the user input in a tablelist using a regex expression.
Usually, I only want to allow digits `0-9` using this:

```
   $w configure -invalidcommand bell -validate key -validatecommand  {regexp {^[0-9]*$} %S}
```

It works fine. Now I want to extend this expression to only allow digits 0-9 or the exact word "Rigid". I tried this, but it allows me to type anything.

```
$w configure -invalidcommand bell -validate key -validatecommand  {regexp {regexp {^([0-9])|^Rigid?\>*$} %S}
```

Comment: You may use `{^(?:[0-9]*|Rigid)$}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider putting your validation code into a proc:

```
$w configure -invalidcommand bell -validate key -validatecommand  {validate %S}

proc validate {data} {
    return [regexp {^(?:[0-9]*|Rigid)$} $data]
    # or
    return [expr {$data eq "Rigid" || [string is integer $data]}]
}
```

or

Answer (score 1):

The `^([0-9])|^Rigid?\>*$` pattern allows matching more than what you need as `^` only applies to the `([0-9])`, a digit, so the first char should be a digit, and the rest can be any. `^Rigid?\>*$` matches a string that starts with `Rigi`, may have a `d` after it, and then has 0+ `>` symbols.

You need

```
{^(?:[0-9]*|Rigid)$}
```

Here, the anchors are applied to both the patterns and will only allow 0+ digits or `Rigid` as a whole string.

Answer (score 0):

$w configure -invalidcommand bell -validate key -validatecommand  {regexp {^[0-9]*$} %S}

> > This will allow either null or "one or multiple digits in the range 0-9".

To ensure at least 1 digit, use + instead of *.

Now coming to your question - allow digits 0-9 or the exact word "Rigid"

> > Use {(^[0-9]+$|^Rigid$)}

Lets site an example which I have just tried:

set a [gets stdin]

if {[regexp -- {(^[0-9]+$|^Rigid$)} $a]} {
    puts "yes"
} else {
    puts "no"
}

Outputs:

> > $ tclsh test1 
> >     12
> >     yes
> >     $ tclsh test1 
> >     Rigid
> >     yes
> >     $ tclsh test1 
> >     rigid
> >     no
> >     $ tclsh test1 
> >     32w
> >     no
> >     $ tclsh test1

no

> > $

Apology for the format. 
[image]